# HELP,, My trigger not working in production but fine in sandbox

Tags: trigger, deployment

i have an issue , i create trigger to create child record under opportunity object, it work fine in sandbox but not working in production

i try to see debug logs of my trigger but my trigger not detected in log
my trigger is already active and working fine in sandbox

can somebody help me ?

here my code trigger
'

```
trigger paymentSyncCreateAndDelete on Payment_Term__c (before update) {
    String opptyId;
    Date achieveDate;

    for(Payment_Term__c sourcePayment : Trigger.new){            

        opptyId = sourcePayment.Opportunity__c;
        achieveDate = sourcePayment.Achievement_Payment_Date__c;

         //When Paid change from false to true, CREATE payment on target
        if(sourcePayment.Paid__c ==true){

            //get oppty payment information
            Opportunity sourcePaymentOppty = [SELECT ID, Sales_Segment__c, Target_Owner_AM__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:sourcePayment.Opportunity__c];

            //search oppty target sales segment with same year and month
            Opportunity[] targetPaymentOppty = [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId, Achievement_Date__c, Target_Owner_NB__c, Target_Owner_AM__c,
                                              Sales_Segment__c, Other_Sales_Segment__c, Product_Name__c FROM Opportunity WHERE 
                                              RecordType.Name='Sales Segment Target' AND FISCAL_MONTH(Achievement_Date__c)=:achieveDate.month()
                                              AND FISCAL_YEAR(Achievement_Date__c)=:achieveDate.year() AND 
                                              Sales_Segment__c=:sourcePaymentOppty.Sales_Segment__c];

            //search oppty target individual with same year and month                                  
            Opportunity[] targetAMPaymentOppty = [SELECT Id,RecordTypeId, Achievement_Date__c, Target_Owner_NB__c, Target_Owner_AM__c,
                                              Sales_Segment__c, Other_Sales_Segment__c, Product_Name__c FROM Opportunity WHERE 
                                              RecordType.Name='Individual Target' AND FISCAL_MONTH(Achievement_Date__c)=:achieveDate.month()
                                              AND FISCAL_YEAR(Achievement_Date__c)=:achieveDate.year() AND 
                                              Target_Owner_AM__c=:sourcePaymentOppty.Target_Owner_AM__c];


            if(targetPaymentOppty.size()>0 && sourcePayment.createdToTarget__c==false){
                Payment_Term__c targetPayment = new Payment_Term__c(Term__c = sourcePayment.Term__c,Opportunity__c = targetPaymentOppty[0].Id, Conversion_Rate_USD__c = sourcePayment.Conversion_Rate_USD__c, Actual_Payment_Date__c= sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Date__c, Actual_Payment_Amount_USD__c= sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_USD__c, Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c= sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c, Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c= sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c,  Plan_Payment_Amount_USD__c= sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_USD__c,  Plan_Payment_Date__c= sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Date__c, Debit_Note_Created__c = true,  Debit_Note_Number__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Number__c,  Debit_Note_Submitted__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Submitted__c,  sourcePayment__c= sourcePayment.Id,Paid__c = true);

                insert targetPayment;   

                if(targetPayment.Id!=null)
                sourcePayment.createdToTarget__c=true;            
            }

            if(targetAMPaymentOppty.size()>0 && sourcePayment.createdToTargetAM__c==false){

                //Payment_Term__c targetPayment = new Payment_Term__c();
                Payment_Term__c targetPayment = new Payment_Term__c(Term__c = sourcePayment.Term__c,Opportunity__c = targetAMPaymentOppty[0].Id,Conversion_Rate_USD__c = sourcePayment.Conversion_Rate_USD__c, Actual_Payment_Date__c= sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Date__c, Actual_Payment_Amount_USD__c= sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_USD__c, Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c= sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c, Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c= sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c, Plan_Payment_Amount_USD__c= sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_USD__c, Plan_Payment_Date__c= sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Date__c, Debit_Note_Created__c = true, Debit_Note_Number__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Number__c, sourcePayment__c= sourcePayment.Id, Paid__c = true,Debit_Note_Submitted__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Submitted__c);

                insert targetPayment;  

                if(targetPayment.Id!=null)
                sourcePayment.createdToTargetAM__c=true;             
            }
        }
        //When Paid change from true to false, DELETE payment on target
        if(Trigger.oldMap.get(sourcePayment.Id).Paid__c==true && sourcePayment.Paid__c ==false){

            //search same Payment on target sales segment
            Payment_Term__c[] targetPayment = [SELECT Id FROM Payment_Term__c WHERE sourcePayment__c=:sourcePayment.Id AND Opportunity__r.RecordType.Name='Sales Segment Target'];


            if(targetPayment.size()>0){
                delete targetPayment[0];
                sourcePayment.createdToTarget__c = false;
            }
            //search same Payment on target sales segment
            Payment_Term__c [] targetPaymentAM = [SELECT Id FROM Payment_Term__c WHERE sourcePayment__c=:sourcePayment.Id  AND Opportunity__r.RecordType.Name='Individual Target'];


            if(targetPaymentAM.size()>0){
                delete targetPaymentAM[0];
                sourcePayment.createdToTargetAM__c = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

'

my test class
'

```
@isTest 
public class testPaymentUpdate{
    static testMethod void testPayment() {

       Id recordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND Name = 'Donation' LIMIT 1].id;
       Id ITrecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND Name = 'Individual Target' LIMIT 1].id;
       Id SSTrecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity' AND Name = 'Sales Segment Target' LIMIT 1].id;
       //CREATE RECORD FROM SCRATCH

       //create account
       Account acc = new Account();
       acc.Name = 'test acc';
       acc.Sales_Segment__c = 'Corporate';
       insert acc;

       //create opportunity donation
       Opportunity opptySource = new Opportunity();
       opptySource.AccountId=acc.Id;
       opptySource.Name ='test oppty';
       opptySource.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 9, 17);
       opptySource.StageName ='6 - MoU in Process';
       opptySource.Target_Owner_AM__c=UserInfo.getUserId();
       opptySource.RecordTypeId= recordTypeId;
       insert opptySource;

       //create opportunity individual target
       Opportunity opptyIndividualTarget = new Opportunity();
       opptyIndividualTarget.Name ='test oppty';
       opptyIndividualTarget.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 9, 1);
       opptyIndividualTarget.Target_Owner_AM__c=UserInfo.getUserId();
       opptyIndividualTarget.Amount_AM__c=50000;
       opptyIndividualTarget.StageName ='Target'; 
       opptyIndividualTarget.RecordTypeId= ITrecordTypeId;
       insert opptyIndividualTarget;

       //create opportunity sales segment target
       Opportunity opptySalesSegmentTarget= new Opportunity();
       opptySalesSegmentTarget.Name ='test oppty';
       opptySalesSegmentTarget.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 9, 1);
       opptySalesSegmentTarget.Sales_Segment__c = 'Corporate';
       opptySalesSegmentTarget.Amount_AM__c=50000;
       opptySalesSegmentTarget.StageName ='Target'; 
       opptySalesSegmentTarget.RecordTypeId = SSTrecordTypeId;
       insert opptySalesSegmentTarget;

       //create source Payment
       Payment_Term__c sourcePayment = new Payment_Term__c();
       sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c = 1000000;
       sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 9, 17);
       sourcePayment.Opportunity__c = opptySource.Id;
       sourcePayment.Term__c = '1';
       insert sourcePayment;

       sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c = 1000000;
       sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 9, 17);
       sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Created__c = true;
       sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Number__c = '123810283';
       sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Submitted__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 9, 17);
       sourcePayment.Paid__c = true;
       sourcePayment.createdToTarget__c=true;
       sourcePayment.createdToTargetAM__c=true;
       update sourcePayment;

       Payment_Term__c targetPayment = new Payment_Term__c();
       targetPayment.Opportunity__c = opptySalesSegmentTarget.Id;
       targetPayment.sourcePayment__c = sourcePayment.Id;
       targetPayment.Term__c = sourcePayment.Term__c;
       targetPayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c = sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c;
       targetPayment.Plan_Payment_Date__c = sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Date__c;
       targetPayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c = sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c;
       targetPayment.Actual_Payment_Date__c = sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Date__c;
       targetPayment.Debit_Note_Created__c = true;
       targetPayment.Debit_Note_Number__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Number__c;
       targetPayment.Debit_Note_Submitted__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Submitted__c;
       targetPayment.Paid__c = true;
       insert targetPayment;

       Payment_Term__c targetPaymentAM = new Payment_Term__c();
       targetPaymentAM.Opportunity__c = opptyIndividualTarget.Id;
       targetPaymentAM.sourcePayment__c = sourcePayment.Id;
       targetPaymentAM.Term__c = sourcePayment.Term__c;
       targetPaymentAM.Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c = sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Amount_IDR__c;
       targetPaymentAM.Plan_Payment_Date__c = sourcePayment.Plan_Payment_Date__c ;
       targetPaymentAM.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c = sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c;
       targetPaymentAM.Actual_Payment_Date__c = sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Date__c;
       targetPaymentAM.Debit_Note_Created__c = true;
       targetPaymentAM.Debit_Note_Number__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Number__c;
       targetPaymentAM.Debit_Note_Submitted__c = sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Submitted__c;
       targetPaymentAM.Paid__c = true;
       insert targetPaymentAM;

       sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Amount_IDR__c = null;
       sourcePayment.Actual_Payment_Date__c = null;
       sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Created__c = false;
       sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Number__c = '';
       sourcePayment.Debit_Note_Submitted__c = null;
       sourcePayment.Paid__c=false;         
       update sourcePayment;
    }
}
```

'

Regards,
Brian

Comment: Can you provide your trigger code?

Comment: is the problem (1) that it doesn't deploy to PROD? or (2) that it deploys to PROD but fails to execute properly?   If #2, delete the testmethod from the question as it is irrelevant

Answer (score 3):

You are using SOQL in a for loop. In a sandbox with limited number of data, you may not exceed the 100, but on a prod, it is more probable. But the fact is that, even if you are in a prod or sandbox, you should never place SOQL in a loop.

Comment: do you have reference so i can improve my code? @vanessen

Comment: When we reach that level where we are tempted to execute soql for each line, we just use map or set to store the field value use for the where clause.

Comment: @FebrianTarigan See e.g. [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices).